# Error 404 with ASP .net MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-404

I'm starting a new MVC2 project on visual studio 2010 when I try with the local webserver I can access to the page localhost/Melomane/Inscription.
But when I upload the project on my school webserver I can't access to the URL/Melomane/Inscription

I've a 404 error http://info-timide.iut.u-bordeaux1.fr/2011-2012/gdesbiey/ASP/Melomane/Inscription

The bootstrap is not used the application try to access a directory Melomane/Inscription instead of the bootstrap.

It's a problem of the configuration of the server ?
Or I can resolve it on my application ?

Comment: @guillaumne: what version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It could be routing issue, I recommend you using URL Routing Debugger to test if it's okey on your server first:

- http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: There's a new [version](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx).

Comment: I've already try this solution and I see that the Physical access path is : \\info\www\perso\2011-2012\gdesbiey\ASP\Melomane\Inscription
instead of a real file

Comment: @guillaume I have a feeling the fact that it's trying to look at the physical path instead of using routing is your problem. I'd go through the usual steps: make sure iis/app pools are set up correctly, make sure you've copied everything over, check event log to see if something unusual happened.